# External Handlebars template in Ember App

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have the following Code

```
    Todos = Ember.Application.create();

    Todos.Todo = Ember.Object.extend({
        title: null,
        isDone: false
    });

    Todos.TodosController = Ember.Object.extend({
        // We need an array to hold our Todo objects
        todos: Ember.A(),

        init: function(){
            debugger;
            var items = this.get('todos');
            items.addObject(Todos.Todo.create({title: "This is an Ember Item"}));
            items.addObject(Todos.Todo.create({title: "This is another Ember Item"}));
        },

        remainingCount: function(){
            return this.get('todos').filterProperty('isDone', false).length;
        }.property('todos.@each.isDone')

    });

    Todos.controller = Todos.TodosController.create();

    Todos.TodoView = Ember.View.extend({
        templateName: 'todos'
    });

</script>
```

I have the following handlebars hook defined inside the thml. But for some reason the template is not being rendered. When I inspect `Handlebars.templates` I see todos listed in the Object returned. What am I missing here.

[image]

**Edit**

Is it possible to define a template inside a .handlebars file at all ?

**Edit**

I did this inside app.js.

```
$.extend(Ember.TEMPLATES, Ember.TEMPLATES, Ember.Handlebars.templates);
```

But that didn't seem to help either. As you can see in the image below, the templates are now listed in `Ember.TEMPLATES`. But for some reason it is not picking them up.

[image]

Also I don't have any html between body tags. I am not sure if I should have anything there.

`<body></body>`

Comment: Where is your todos template defined? You defined it externally? What are you using to compile it?

Comment: I am using external templates in a file called `todos.handlebars`. I compile them as a part of the build process. So a file named templates-compiled.js gets downloaded.

Comment: There are a few things going on here: You're creating an instance of the controller manually and you're not using naming conventions properly: the controller should be `TodosController` extending `Ember.ArrayController` instead of `Ember.Object` so you don't have to define a `todos` property and just use `content` instead. This also brings several other features baked in the controller. Also note that using Handlebars in Ember is a little different than other frameworks. You should store your compiled templates in `Ember.TEMPLATES` collection via `Ember.Handlebars.compile('your template')`

Comment: And you're sure the precompiled templates file is loaded in the client before your app starts using the templates? And you should have a template named `application` which is your layout.

Comment: Yepper, it is one of the first files, even before Ember.js.

Comment: As I said before, you need a template named `application`. You'll load the `TodosView` calling the `{{view}}` helper or the `{{outlet}}` helper along the proper routes for your app, but it's required to have an `application` template. I strongly recommend that you read the [guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MilkyWayJoe

What you said about application template helped me thankyou. I think my precompiler is what is causing me problems. I am able to view my partial inside the application template now. But, the `linkTo` doesn't seem to work for some reason. `linkTo` works if I declare the templates inside the html page!!

This is the precompiler in context. 
http://blog.selvakn.in/2012/05/precompiling-handlerbars-tempates-with.html

I am able to view the files now. One would need to add the following lines to `app.js` to get it working however.

```
// To register partials
$.each(Ember.Handlebars.templates, function(i, template){
    if(i.indexOf('_') === 0){
        Ember.Handlebars.partials[i.substring(1, i.length)]  = template;
    }
});

// To let Ember.Handlebars know about the newly added templates
$.extend(Ember.TEMPLATES, Ember.TEMPLATES, Ember.Handlebars.templates);
```

What helped me is adding the templates one at a time to the html body first and then moving  them into their own files. Also remember that the `data-template-name` is not a property you can ignore. It causes all kinds of problems if one does.

**Edit**

This node package works better.

[Emberjs Handlebars precompiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860512/emberjs-handlebars-precompiling)

Answer (score 1):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860512/emberjs-handlebars-precompiling/12433660#12433660)

To precompile handlebars templates you have to install [ember-precompile package](https://github.com/gabrielgrant/node-ember-precompile)

If you need make utility (on Mac) [install it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570034/issue-installing-jsdom-on-mac/11593832#11593832)

Then include precompiled templates into your index.html like here:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        App = Ember.Application.create({});
    </script>
    <!-- templates -->
    <script src="js/templates/templates.js"></script>
    <!-- app init -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        App.initialize();
    </script>
```